# ¿Cómo poner color alternativo en jQuery Datepicker para intervalos de fechas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-datepicker

¿Hay alguna forma de pintar de diferentes colores los días del  [jQuery Datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)?

Por ejemplo:

[image: datepiker]

Donde el color azul indica la primera sesión, verde la segunda y rojo la tercera.

Tengo 3 sesiones (3 intervalos)

Comment: ¿Has intentado algo?

Comment: @CésarBustíos Inspeccionando el HTML generado veo que tiene los siguientes atributos `data-year="2015"` y `data-month="11"` pero no para el dia, mi idea era generar el css dinamicamente desde el servidor, pero sin el dia no me sirve

Comment: Todo lo que has intentado debes considerarlo en tu pregunta, así es más fácil que otros te ayuden y vean tu esfuerzo

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Puedes utilizar la opción [beforeShowDay](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay).  Es una función que aunque no muy intuitiva te permite personalizar los elementos de días.

Dígamos que quieres marcar los días "8"

```
$(function() { // $(document).ready(...
    $('#tu-input-fecha').datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: function(date) {
           if (date.getDate() === 8) {
               return [true, 'bg-red', 'titulo opcional'];
           }

           return [true];
        }
    });
});
```

La función que le pasas a `beforeShowDay` es invocada automáticamente por cada día de la página del calendario que va a ser mostrada.  En la función recibirás un objeto `Date` con el día correspondiente, con esto puedes decidir si vas a modificar el elemento.

Ahora lo que no es obvio es que tienes que devolver un *array* con 3 valores:

- El primero indica si el día es seleccionable `true/false`
- El segundo es un *string* con el nombre de la clase css que quieres asignarle al elemento
- El tercero es un *title* opcional que aparece cuando haces *hover*

Finalmente siempre tienes que devolver por lo menos `[true]` para que el resto de días sean seleccionables.

Como detalle adicional

Se debe poner el estilo al elemento hijo `a` de nuestra clase, usando `background`, con `background-color` no se tiene resultado ya que el css de jQuery UI lo escribe con `background` y se aplica al final, además de usar `¡important;`

```
.dia-especial a{
    background: #ff00ff url(images/ui-bg_flat_90_ffffff_40x100.png) 50% 50% repeat-x !important; font-weight: normal; color: #3f3f3f;
}
```

Comment: Perfecto, ya lo pude validar ;)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes ir tomando los elementos de acuerdo a las cantidades que necesites utilizando el método [Slice](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp)

```
$(".ui-state-default").slice(0,3).css("background-color","red")
```

La clase ui-state-default es la que tiene el elemento de día, y en el ejemplo se toman los primeros 3 elementos.

Faltaría determinar la lógica para determinar los periodos en base a tus necesidades